# Inputs on Ember refresh page when a user hits Enter key

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember CLI and have noticed odd behaviour.  When the user clicks into the input and presses the enter key, the page refreshes.

My page has a basic element like this that is NOT part of any form:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="per_page" value="50">
```

I am currently serving the page via:

```
ember cli
```

So node is hosting and has the fancy live reload thing going on so that when I update a page that is part of the underlying app.

So what is causing a page reload the enter key pressed inside an input?  Could it be node or live reload?  Are inputs just supposed to refresh a page when a user presses the enter key and I missed that in my HTML for dummies book?

**Better still, how can I intercept and instead call a function via:

```
{{action** "myFunction"}}
```

Comment: I never fixed this issue so much and destroyed my project and started over.  It has not surfaced for me since and I'm still using Ember regularly so I must have been doing something wrong at the time.

Answer (score 7):

That happens because when you hit Enter, form gets submitted which results in page reload. what you need to do is set `onsubmit="return false"` on the form so nothing happens during submit. you can bind input to execute some action by adding action attribute `action="doSomething"`

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
        {{input type="text" action="createComment" value=topic id="inputTopic"}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** In Ember 3+ you now use the `{{on}}` modifier to setup events on elements.

```
<form {{on 'submit' this.submitForm}}>
  <!-- the rest of your form here -->

  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the action defined like so

```js
@action
submitForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Your code
}
```

---

Historically Ember has handled this use case with the following code:

```
<form {{action 'submitForm' on='submit'}}>
  <!-- the rest of your form here -->

  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This prevents the form from refreshing the page.

There is another method that gives you more control, by giving you the event so you can manage that yourself:

```
<form onsubmit={{action 'submitForm'}}>
  <!-- the rest of your form here -->

  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

In this case, you will get an event and will have to call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the page refresh.

```
actions: {
  submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

This is a running example of the two: https://ember-twiddle.com/827820958e054f7af57b7677630729fc?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - what worked for me, was to overwrite the keyPress Event in the input component like this:

```
keyPress: function (e) {
    var keyCodeEnter = 13;

    if (e.keyCode === keyCodeEnter) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help someone in the future! :)